# how to create and run several temp tables one after one in PostgreSQL and consolidate this data in another temp table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, temp-tables

I have MS SQL background and now I am beginner at PostgreSQL.I want to create temp table T1 and then the data from T1 use in another temp Table T2 and so till T4, I wrote the script but cant run it all together, I have to run it one by one. Also the temp tables drop after some period by itself. without Drop Table order.

Comment: With Postgres more often than not, using temp tables is the wrong approach. Just write one query that returns what you want, e.g. using multiple CTEs. But without seeing your code this is impossible to answer

Comment: "I wrote the script but cant run it all together,"  What ERROR do you get?

Comment: In MS SQL you can run several Selects together, I mean Select data From Table1, Select Data2 From Table2, and when you run script, first it generates first table and then second, but here it stops working after first select.

Comment: If you need to do some operations such as upsert or rely on TEMP tables to perform calculations you could perform all queries and you specify that only on commit the TEMP table will drop:  "CREATE TEMP TABLE foobarr ON COMMIT DROP;"